# Sentry Vue doesn't show set user when logging error

Tags: vue.js, sentry

I started using Sentry to log our vue front-end errors and read in the docs that you can set your user data as needed to identify the errors better using Sentry.setUser(...).

This is what I am currently doing:

```js
// mutation after successfully login in
login: (state, userProfile) => {
    Sentry.setUser({
      id: userProfile.employee.id,
      username: userProfile.employee.firstName + userProfile.employee.lastName,
    });
    // the rest of code
},

// capturing an axios error is done as follows
Sentry.captureException(error);
```

Sentry does log that event, but the set user is not shown and only ip is shown:

[image]

Checking the network tab in browser odes show that the set user is actually posted to sentry

Comment: @SinisterBeard no I haven't found a solution, but on the new project just using Sentry.setUser({ id: user.id }) does work now. I am not sure why but it just fixed itself